# Is there r.v. that are neither continuous nor discrete?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Is there r.v. that are neither discrete nor continuous ? My definition of continuous r.v. is that $x\longmapsto f_X(x)$ (the mass function) is continuous and the r.v. is discrete if there is a countable set $\mathcal D$ s.t. $\mathbb P\{X\in \mathcal D\}=1$. So is there r.v. s.t. $f_X$ is not continuous but there is no countable set $\mathcal D$ s.t. $\mathbb P\{X\in \mathcal D\}=1$.

For example something as $\mathbb P\{X\in \mathcal C\}=1$ where $\mathcal C$ is the Cantor set, but there is no countable subset $\mathcal D$ of $\mathcal C$ s.t. $\mathcal P\{X\in \mathcal D\}=1$, but $f_X$ is not continuous. Does such r.v. exist ? If yes, which one ? If no, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just think of a random variable that is $=2$ with probability $\frac12$ and is taken from a unifmormly distributed varable in $[0,1]$ otherwise ...

Comment: In my course, when we have to prove something for a r.v. we always have to prove when $X$ is continuous, and after when $X$ is discrete. So if I understand, it's not enough, right ? (For example, we had to compute $\mathbb P\{X+Y\leq z\}$ where $X,Y$ are iid and we had to prove that $\mathbb P\{X+Y\leq z\}=\sum_{y\in \mathcal D_Y} f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)$ if $Y$ is discrete and $\mathbb P\{X+Y\leq z\}=\int_{\mathbb R}f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$ if $Y$ continuous. Therefore, it's not enough, right ? We also have to consider when $Y$ is neither discrete or continuous, no ? So how can I proceed ?